# How to configure the bundles JRE installation directory (on MacOS)

Tags: install4j

install4j can easily bundle a JRE with the application. On Windows (and linux) the JRE is installed in a sub-directory jre (of the application). On MacOS it seems to be in .install4j/jre.bundle

How to configure install4j to place the JRE into a jre directory? It seems to be the default location for any RCP base application. Would be nice if that directory could be used for the bundled JRE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The location of the JRE bundle is currently not adjustable. However, you can use a "Move files and directories" action to move the JRE to a different location after the "Install files" action has run. In that case you have to call

```
String newJreHome = ...;
JVMSelector.setPreferredJVM(newJreHome);
```

so that the launcher and the uninstaller will use the JRE from the new location.

Comment: How do I know whether the application is using the relocated jre? For example: alongside the bundled jre which is used by install4j at installation runtime I want to unpack another jre (e.g. with another version) to a folder like 'java' or 'jre-xy' and relocate the jre-home as you mentioned so that this will be used by my application. It seems to have no effect because my log output shows the 'java.home' is still pointing to the bundled one.

Comment: Check the file .install4j\pref_jre.cfg

Comment: Could there be a problem when the bundled jre for the installer is a 32bit jre and the unpacked jre is a 64bit jre? The background for that is the following: the installer should analyse the os platform (x86 or x64) and than should switch/use the jre suitable to the os platform. That's the requirement I have. Therefore I tried to relocate the jre to the unpacked 64bit version on a 64bit os platform (windows).

Comment: The launcher will ignore the JRE in .install4j\pref_jre.cfg if the bitness does not match the generated launcher. You can start the launcher with the argument /create-i4j-log from the command line to debug the Java search sequence.

Comment: Okay, that was what I expected. Thank you for your confirmation. I will look for another solution/workaround maybe with two installer bundled in an 32bit "meta"-installer or something like that.