# Is it possible to specify the location of the static bundled jre in install4j?

Tags: install4j

I am evaluating install4j as a replacement for our current installer and I would like to keep the same structure on disk for the installed program.
Currently, our bundle JRE is located at a different location than /jre, and with the default setting install4j copy the bundled jre into the /jre directory.

Is is possible to specify the location of the bundle JRE (either via the XML file or the GUI)?

Comment: I guess the answer is the same is *no* as answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041797/how-to-configure-the-bundles-jre-installation-directory-on-macos?rq=1